# Apache nifi and kafka microservice

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, microservices, apache-nifi

I'm quite new in Apache Nifi but I'm encountering some issues trying to connect a kafka microservice (with a producer) with Apache nifi consumer.

Basically, I have a docker-compose like this:

```
zookeeper:
  container_name: zookeeper_test
  image: wurstmeister/zookeeper #zookeeper:3.5.7
  ports:
  - 2181:2181

kafka:
  container_name: kafka_test
  image: wurstmeister/kafka #:2.13-2.6.0
  ports:
  - 9092:9092
  environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
  depends_on: 
      - zookeeper
      - kafkaui

kafkaui:
  container_name: kafka-ui_test
  image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
  environment: 
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME=kafka
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=kafka:9092
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER= zookeeper:2181
  ports:
      - 6789:8080

test:
  container_name: test
  build:
      context: ./test
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  depends_on:
      - kafka
  command: python test.py
```

test is my producer:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json
from time import sleep

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='kafka:9092')
json_message = {"hello":"world"}


for i in range(1000):
   producer.send("INPUT", json.dumps(json_message).encode('utf-8')) 
   producer.flush()
   sleep(1)
```

Through the KafkaUI I'm able to see the topic INPUT that has been sent.

In the Apache nifi dashboard, I set a ConsumerKafka_2.6 with these parameters:
Kafka broker: localhost:9092
Group ID: 1
Topic: INPUT

then I connected to this a funnel when "success", just to see the message received. Unfortunately, doing this, I do not see anything received. I just see a lot of tasks in the consumerkafka box but no elements in the queue connected to the funnel. I expect to see the json received, isn'it? May I miss something?

[image: Kafka Consumer Settings 1]

[image: Kafka Consumer Settings 2]

[image: Workflow]

Comment: Is the producer running after NiFi has started consuming?  Alternatively, is NiFi set to consume from earliest or latest?

Comment: the producer started BEFORE the NiFi consumer. Offset reset is set to latest

Comment: Have you tried a Kafka console consumer to verify there are messages in the topic? Set the starting offset to EARLIEST. What is the Topic name? The Python producer says topic = INPUT but your NiFi config says the Topic = SL.CPTI.INPUT.

Comment: Hi, yes. I wrote input since I try also different topics. Don’t care…the topic is the same for both. I also tried Kafka ui microservices to see if the topic is available and it is. So it is not a problem of topic or sending message

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem is in the conncetin with kafka broker. When I dockerize apache nifi (instead of using it as localhost), putting as kafka browser url kafka:9092, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

From @alexmark's comment, the NiFi consumer has offset reset set to latest.  This means that if there's no committed offset for the consumer group, NiFi will effectively ignore messages already produced to the topic.

Setting offset reset to earliest will change that behavior to consuming all messages in the topic, after which the last consumed offset will be committed so that the next time consumption starts it will be where the consumer left off.

If changing offset reset to earliest has no effect, it's likely that NiFi committed an offset from when it was running before: changing the consumer group (retaining offset reset as earliest) is the easiest way to address that (there is tooling within Kafka to inspect and modify committed offsets)

Comment: Hi Levi, thanks for your response. I did what you wrote me but had no effects. Kafka is still running and I did not stop it. I aslo added screenshots of the configuration and workflow of apache nifi.

Comment: PS as you can see the queue is always 0